# How do I switch to Cinnamon/Nemo at the login screen?

Tags: 13.04, apt, cinnamon

Kind of a new user to Ubuntu, and need some help. I tried to install the Cinnamon desktop (Nemo, I think is its code-name?) environment on Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit) and I typed the following into terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon nemo
```

And I updated again, just to be sure. No harm in double-checking, right?

Everything checked out okay, no error messages or anything, but the DE switcher at login doesn't appear anywhere on the screen. And after I type my password nothing else appears. Anyone who can help, I'd love to start using the awesome environment!

Comment: just log out and then at the log in screen choose cinnamon desktop. Can't remember what the icon looks like, but it's quite easy to guess, I mean what can go wrong?

Comment: @Alvar I don't know how to select the DE at the new Unity/LightDM login screen either... There's simply no button (wrench icon) in the box with username/password. (nothing like http://linuxlookup.com/files/imagecache/800x600/ubuntu_11.10_login.png) (that's why I am using KDM)

Comment: isn't there like a foot or something next to your name?

Comment: If you can't do it there, then try the system settings, your account and then select the default DE to be the one you want. reboot.

Comment: btw, the `sudo apt-get update` doesn't update the system it just checks if new software is available for download. you need to `sudo apt-get upgrade` to actually install the upgrades. use `apt-get dist-upgrade` to install new kernel versions and such. @gertvdijk looked in system settings?

Comment: @Alvar, I did what you said and it worked for me. Did anyone actually try clicking the Ubuntu logo by the user name? Because after I used sudo apt-get uprade, I clicked it and it showed me the new switch option.

Answer (score 3):

On the login screen click on the Ubuntu logo next to your name and select what Desktop to use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using LightDM (the default logon screen), look next to your name. There should be a small round button depicting the Ubuntu logo against a white background. If you click this button, you be given a list of environments to use. Simply click on Cinnamon, then log in as usuall.

The next time you either logoff, or reboot the computer, LightDM will remember which environment you used (Cinnamon) and will reuses it unless you specify otherwise.

However, the button will loose the Ubuntu logo, and show only a white background, so if youcant remember where it is, perhaps you should consider using a different logon screen, such as [MDM](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/06/mdm-display-manager-and-mdm-themes-for.html). If you choose to follow the installation instructions in that link, you'll eventually be asked to choose your default logon manager.